# inAppbrowser done button text change

Tags: ios, web-applications, cordova

in my phonegap iOS app, i m using cordova2.7.0 and using inAppwebbrowser, when it opens done button coming to bottom, i need to chnge text of 'Done' to french name, so please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Please i m new , why u voted down me please give reason, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can do it** by native in `Xcode` ,in phonegap **currently can't do it**, customizing 'Done' button text is a feature that the Phonegap team is working on. You can read more about it [**here**.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2459)

> **how in xcode:**

Locate `CDVInAppBrowser.m` as shown

```
coredovalib -> classes -> commands -> CDVInAppBrowser.m
```

and paste below code snippet where close button properties are set

```
    self.closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"my text"
 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(close)];
```

Comment: so, it means not possible now.

Comment: i wanna to accept both answer but, at a time only one can be selected, that i did't know..thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

On CDVInAppBrowser.m file replace

Replace this

```
 if (browserOptions.closebuttoncaption != nil) {
       [self.inAppBrowserViewController setCloseButtonTitle:browserOptions.closebuttoncaption];
  }
```

to

```
if (browserOptions.closebuttoncaption == nil) {
    NSLog(@"hiii if");
    [self.inAppBrowserViewController setCloseButtonTitle:@"Your French Name hear"];
}
```

Comment: i tried first post of mvp and it working, is there any wrong with first post, please let me explain...thanks for answer..thanks

Comment: not much but i have directly set text from setCloseButtonTitle method as parameter

Answer (score 0):

**Open** `${projectname}/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m` with an editor of your choice.

in the init function, look for this:

```
self.toolbar = YES;
self.closebuttoncaption = nil;
self.toolbarposition = kInAppBrowserToolbarBarPositionBottom;
self.clearcache = NO;
self.clearsessioncache = NO;
```

**Change** 
    `self.closebuttoncaption = nil;` => `self.closebuttoncaption = @"your text";`

The Main advantage here is that it builds correct and you don't have to change it every time you build.
Also it is recommend to change the text in the init function, so don't have to change it in the setter function.

P.S.: Im using org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser 0.6.0 "InAppBrowser"

Answer (score 0):

In Cordova InAppBrowser 1.7.0 you can supply the close button text as `closebuttoncaption` when calling the InAppBrowser rather than having to change the code of Cordova:

```
myIAB.create('http:/blah, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close');
```

And also in `window.open`:

```
window.open('http://blah','_blank','location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close');
```

Other `browserOptions` listed in CDVInAppBrowserOptions with the defaults:

```
location = YES;
toolbar = YES;
closebuttoncaption = nil;
toolbarposition = kInAppBrowserToolbarBarPositionBottom;
clearcache = NO;
clearsessioncache = NO;
enableviewportscale = NO;
mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction = NO;
allowinlinemediaplayback = NO;
keyboarddisplayrequiresuseraction = YES;
suppressesincrementalrendering = NO;
hidden = NO;
disallowoverscroll = NO;
```